# Convergence of Infinite Series - Complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

Having trouble with this infinite series and deciding whether it converges or diverges.

The series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2+i^n}$$

I tried using the ratio test but get stuck in the computation. Ended up with something like $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2+i^n}{2+i^n*i}$$

Do I have to take the modulus of the rational first? what's the modulus of $i^n$?

Comment: Modulus of $i^n$ is $|i^n| = |i|^n = 1$.

Comment: @Clayton: There seems to  be a bug in the auto-creation of comments for duplicate votes.

Comment: @MartinR: I understand. I wasn't meaning to suggest you did something wrong. I was just surprised at the link haha

Comment: @Clayton: Reported as a bug on meta: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29738/42969.

Comment: @MartinR: Upvoted. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Clayton: The problem had already been reported: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29736/42969

Comment: @Martin: Thanks once more. Upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

The absolute value of the term within the summation does not tend to zero, so the summation diverges. The value of $i^n$ is either $i,-1,-i$ or $1$ and hence the value of the summation is:
$$\frac{1}{2+i}+\frac{1}{2-1}+\frac{1}{2-i}+\frac{1}{2+1}+...$$
$$=\frac{2-i}{5}+1+\frac{2+i}{5}+\frac{1}{3}+...$$
...which clearly diverges.

Comment: To be perfectly clear, $\left|\frac{1}{2+i^n}\right|\geq\frac13$ for all $n$. :)